URL not updating in nested Navigator in Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a main Navigator and a nested Navigator within a SetupFlow widget. The URL updates correctly for the first-level routes but does not change for the second-level routes within SetupFlow.
Here is my setup:
const routeHome = '/';
const routeSettings = '/settings';
const routePrefixDeviceSetup = '/setup/';
const routeDeviceSetupStartPage = 'find_devices';
const routeDeviceSetupSelectDevicePage = 'select_device';
const routeDeviceSetupConnectingPage = 'connecting';
const routeDeviceSetupFinishedPage = 'finished';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        late Widget page;
        if (settings.name == routeHome) {
          page = const HomeScreen();
        } else if (settings.name == routeSettings) {
          page = const SettingsScreen();
        } else if (settings.name!.startsWith(routePrefixDeviceSetup)) {
          final subRoute = settings.name!.substring(routePrefixDeviceSetup.length);
          page = SetupFlow(setupPageRoute: subRoute);
        } else {
          throw Exception('Unknown route: ${settings.name}');
        }

        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (context) { return page; },
          settings: settings,
        );
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  );
}

@immutable
class SetupFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  const SetupFlow({super.key, required this.setupPageRoute});
  final String setupPageRoute;

  @override
  SetupFlowState createState() => SetupFlowState();
}

class SetupFlowState extends State<SetupFlow> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  void _onDiscoveryComplete() {
    _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeDeviceSetupSelectDevicePage);
  }

  void _onDeviceSelected(String deviceId) {
    _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeDeviceSetupConnectingPage);
  }

  void _onConnectionEstablished() {
    _navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeDeviceSetupFinishedPage);
  }

  Future<void> _onExitPressed() async {
    final isConfirmed = await _isExitDesired();
    if (isConfirmed && mounted) { _exitSetup(); }
  }

  Future<bool> _isExitDesired() async {
    return await showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
                content: const Text('If you exit device setup, your progress will be lost.'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(true); }, child: const Text('Leave')),
                  TextButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(false); }, child: const Text('Stay')),
                ],
              );
            }) ?? false;
  }

  void _exitSetup() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        if (didPop) return;
        if (await _isExitDesired() && context.mounted) { _exitSetup(); }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: _buildFlowAppBar(),
        body: Navigator(
          key: _navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: widget.setupPageRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            late Widget page;
            switch (settings.name) {
              case routeDeviceSetupStartPage:
                page = WaitingPage(message: 'Searching for nearby bulb...', onWaitComplete: _onDiscoveryComplete);
                break;
              case routeDeviceSetupSelectDevicePage:
                page = SelectDevicePage(onDeviceSelected: _onDeviceSelected);
                break;
              case routeDeviceSetupConnectingPage:
                page = WaitingPage(message: 'Connecting...', onWaitComplete: _onConnectionEstablished);
                break;
              case routeDeviceSetupFinishedPage:
                page = FinishedPage(onFinishPressed: _exitSetup);
                break;
              default:
                throw Exception('Unknown route: ${settings.name}');
            }
            return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (context) { return page; }, settings: settings);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildFlowAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(onPressed: _onExitPressed, icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left)),
      title: const Text('Bulb Setup'),
    );
  }
}

The URL changes for the first-level routes (routeHome, routeSettings) but not for the second-level routes within SetupFlow. How can I ensure the URL updates correctly for the nested Navigator as well?


Would love to know if you resolved this. I'm having the same issue.
